# Yii2 MaskedInput with alias 'url' limits input to 60 characters

Tags: url, yii2, maskedinput

I am using the following code in Yii2:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'link')->widget(MaskedInput::classname(), [
        'clientOptions' => [
            'alias' => 'url',
        ],
]) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

It seems, that the input field is limited to 60 characters. How to remove this limitations?

See the URL example on: http://demos.krajee.com/masked-input

Comment: Could it be caused by a validation rule for 'link'?

Comment: @robsch, the validations in my case are: 'url' and  'string', 'max' => 255. However it is truncated at 60 characters. Kartik's page is a simple demo, but interestingly it is tranceted to 60 charactes also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limitation is in **jquery.inputmask**. See https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/863. This limitation will disappear if the issue is solved and the new **jquery.inputmask.js** is included in Yii2 bower package.